# How to draw text in higher resolution

Tags: c#, text, fonts, sfml

I'm using views to allow the user to zoom in and pan around an image in my program. The only problem is even though the simple shapes render cleanly, text renders at the resolution of the starting screen. As seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTZ3T.png). Is there any way the text can be rendered with higher detail or do I have to pre-render all text at a higher resolution.

Here is the code, it's not exactly what I'm using. It's a minimal example.

```
Font myFont = new Font("fonts/arial.ttf");

Text myText = new Text("my text", myFont);
window.Draw(myText);
```

And then I'd have controls to move around the view and zoom in, etc.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing the view will show you is the resolution you drew the text in. The zoom of the view will only calculate the new size on screen and calculate, it will not redraw anything in a higher resolution.

So yes, if you want the text resolution be higher, you need to draw it in a higher resolution.

Answer (score 0):

So if you don't already know. There is a function setSize  for the text, and i can say it doesn't change the quality of the text. Maybe if you zoom too much but you will never need to zoom it so much so you can even see the pixels of the font. =)

Comment: Ja, that's what I've done. I've made a function that draws text at a higher size to a RenderTexture then puts that on a sprite, scales it down and caches it if I draw the same text again later.